# Power BI - Redshift odbc driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, powerbi

We are working on power bi connected to a redshift cluster using the default driver that comes within power bi, the simba driver odbc. We are experiencing really poor performance of queries comparing the execution time through power BI and sql workbench. Summarizing the same query takes 4 times more to run within power bi than on sqlworkbench using a jdbc driver.

Is it possible to replace the odbc driver, for the official redshift driver released by Amazon and keep the direct query working?

regards,

tks.

Comment: You should always use the official ODBC or JDBC drivers with Redshift. However I think it's unlikely the ODBC driver is the cause of such a dramatic differences in performance, you should look at the Redshift query history to check if Power BI is actually executing the queries you think it is.

Comment: @Nathan thank you for your reply! I'm getting the queris from the redshift query history and executing outside of powerbi and achieving a better performance.